# Why is is that tellurium(VI) fluoride is completely hydrolysed but iodine(III) fluoride isn't, even in hot water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis

Tellurium(VI) fluoride is completely hydrolysed into tellurium(VI) oxide and hydrofluoric acid, but iodine(III) fluoride isn't, stopping at the iodine(III) fluoride dihydroxide/hydrofluoric acid level, even after extensive warming. Why is it that way, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is $\ce{HIO2}$ even known? My understanding is it isn't.

Comment: Watch proper writing. Repeated confusing 0 and O  in chemical formulas is highly frown upon. Unless you have dyslexia/-graphia conditions, it is usually taken as ignorance and carelessness.

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles. // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Why should tellurium behave like iodine ?

Comment: And why should VI behave like III?

Answer (score 1):

Why not? Tellurium hexafluoride also goes through an intermediate:

> The hydrolysis of tellurium hexafluoride produces the fluoroorthotelluric acids, $\ce{TeF_n(OH)_{6–n}}$, n= 1–4, which undergo complete hydrolysis to orthotelluric acid only over a long period of time.

**Ref.**: Fraser, G.W., & Meikle, G.D. (**1974**). *Hydrolysis of tellurium hexafluoride*. Journal of The Chemical Society, Chemical Communications, 624-625, DOI: [10.1039/C39740000624](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1974/C3/C39740000624)